# Wordpress backend form returns JSON

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins

I developed a small one-file plugin for a wordpress site. It's just adds an upload form for a file that POSTs to itself and then does some stuff with the file's contents once submitted.

It works fine on the staging environment, but on the live server there is a strange problem. Once I submit the form with the file the server does not bring me back to the same page but instead returns the following JSON:

```
{"success":false,"message":"Please enter a message."}
```

I am at loss what could be causing this. Has anybody come across such a problem?

The (simplified plugin):

```
function show_upload_form() {

    if ($_FILES['userfile']) {
        echo "<p>file received</p>";

        $file = fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], "r");

        $data = [];
        while (!feof($file)) {
            $data[] = fgetcsv($file,null,';');
        }

        foreach ($data as $line) {

            $pid = $line[0];

            if (isset($line[1])) {
                $price = trim(str_replace(',', '.', $line[1]));
            } else {
                $price = "";
            }

            if (isset($line[2])) {
                $title = trim(iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $line[2]));
            } else {
                $title = "";
            }

            global $wpdb;
            $product_ids = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND meta_value='%s'", $pid));
            foreach ($product_ids as $product_id) {
                $elem = $product_id->post_id;

                if ($price != "") {
                    update_post_meta($elem, '_price', $price);
                    update_post_meta($elem, '_sale_price', $price);
                    update_post_meta($elem, '_regular_price', $price);
                }

                if ($title != "") {
                    wp_update_post(array(
                        'ID'           => $elem,
                        'post_title'   => $title,
                    ));
                }
            }
            echo "<p>Produkt #".$pid;
            if ($price != "") {
                echo " - new price: ".$price."€";
            }
            if ($title != "") {
                echo "- new title: ".$title;
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "<form method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">";
        echo "<label for=\"file\">Select a file:</label>";
        echo "<input type=\"file\" name=\"userfile\" id=\"file\">";
        echo "<br /><br />";
        echo "<button>Upload File</button>";
        echo "<form>";
    }
}
```

I appreciate any input.

Comment: Are there any validations for form? Or any email functionality ?

Comment: The form itself doesn't validate anything. The function on post just parses the values (it's a csv file) and then updates some database entries accordingly. But it never gets that far as the json get in the way.

Comment: Any email functionality or anything?

Comment: Can you also add your plugin  code If possible?

Comment: I've added the remaining code. No email functionality. But as I said, we never reach that code ...

Comment: Where is you JSON code here?

Comment: There is no JSON code. Which is exactly the problem. I get a JSON response when submitting the form and I'm not using JSON ..

Comment: What is the file size of CSV?

Comment: The file I need to eventually process has a few thousand lines with three columns. But for testing purpose I'm using one with three lines, 4 kb, which produces the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<form action="<?=admin_url( 'admin-post.php' ) ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="my_custom_plugin_action"/>
    <input type="submit" value="SEND"/>
</form>

add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_my_custom_plugin_action',array( "class_that_owns_that_function", 'show_upload_form' ) );

public function show_upload_form()
{
    //Here write your code
}
```

Comment: Sadly this leads to the same result, I still get the strange JSON return.

Comment: @asto. Thats strange

Answer (score 0):

Problem disappeared after deactivating and individually reactivating all the plugins for the second or third time. Guess this one will remain a mystery ...